# Scheduling COGNOS 11 report with last month filtered

Tags: cognos, cognos-11

We're trying to schedule a report in Cognos on the 18th of every month showing data from the 18th of the previous month to the 17th of the current month. How would I define this filter? We've previously used something like :

*`[date] between _add_days(current_date,-7 and _add_days(current_date,-1)`*

but haven't been able to work out a way to do that start date as months vary in length. Any suggestions would be greatly appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
[date] between add_days(first_of_month(_add_months(current_date,-1)),18) and add_days(first_of_month(current_date),17)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it